# Using istringstream gives error | Why

Tags: c++, string, split

I have one binary file which I have created. In it, data is stored in binary form but I will show it in human readable form like ;

```
 [someOtherData]6759A_block$[someOtherData]
```

I hold that data "6759A_block$" in temp_S, which is declared as string. Now, I want split first 3 byte away from temp_S, and then store it in unsigned int. To accomplish my wish, I have write below code segment;

```
 unsigned int number;
 { 
 string tmp ( temp_S , 0  ,3 ); 
 istringstream temp_Istream ( tmp ) ;
 temp_Istream >> number;
 }
```

However, when I compile my small program, it gives an error shown below ;

```
error: variable ‘std::istringstream temp_S’ has initializer but incomplete type
```

My questions are :

- What is the meaning of this compiler error ?
- how can I fix that problem, and take first three byte of data to unsigned int ?

EDIT :

- platform linux
- g++

Comment: i didn't get any error using this code. Can you specify your compiler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ compile error: has initializer but incomplete type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428164/c-compile-error-has-initializer-but-incomplete-type)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GCC gives that [error](http://www.ideone.com/FSC2S) when you forget this:

```
#include <sstream> //this is where istringstream is defined
```

Comment: @sehe: Yes. I just tested it, and so changed the answer accordingly.