# C++ compile error: has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, compilation, istringstream

I am coding in Eclipse and have something like the following:

```
#include <ftream>
#include <iostream>

void read_file(){
    char buffer[1025];
    std::istringstream iss(buffer);
}
```

However, when I try to build, I get the following error: `variable 'std::istringstream iss' has initializer but incomplete type`

Any quick thoughts? I have googled around and it seems like most people with this problem simply did not include the right header files which I believe I am doing correctly.

Comment: `std::istringstring`? It's in the `<sstream>` header anyway, though.

Comment: whoops, i typed the question wrong, i have it coded the way you wrote so the problem is still the same

Comment: yep, adding <sstream> made it build correctly, thanks!

Comment: Hard to see what the justification is for reopening. I'll skip and let others make the decision, but it appears to be a simple error.

Comment: Also, I believe the first line should be `#include<fstream>` instead of `#include <ftream>` @Aneem

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You need this include:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Comment: This is practically a bug on the standard library; the class was found but not the method leaving the programmer in the dark about what file to include unless he knows the standard library file names by heart, which is a ridiculous expectation. I hope someone reports it as a bug.

Comment: @jriv I am not sure what are you talking about. cppreference clearly states that the `sstream` header must be included to use `std::istringstream`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream

Comment: @AnisLadramhe: he is talking about  being mislead by `gcc` *error message*, which is not helping the programmer to abide by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Please include either of these:

```
#include<sstream>

using std::istringstream;
```