# get a double out a string c++

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm searching for an efficient way to get a double out of a string in c++. I now the cstring to double function, however I can not use that because this string is the following format:

```
DOUBLE - SPACE - REST OF STRING THAT I ALSO NEED TO SAVE.
```

The problem is that the double can be of different sizes, so how can I get the double efficiently and that I am still able to save the rest of the string.

Comment: What have you tried so far..? Do you have some code you can post to show us what you've tried?

Comment: Have you tried just splitting the string in managable parseable parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `istringstream` to read double value, ignore one character (space was expected), and read rest of line.

```
string s = "1.11 my string";

double d;
string rest;

istringstream iss(s);
iss >> d;
iss.ignore(); // ignore one character, space expected.
getline(iss, rest, '\0');
```

Comment: +1, but it's nice to see `if (iss >> d && iss.ignore() && getline(iss, rest)) ...; else std::cerr << "failed\n";` - too many beginning C++ programmers assume input succeeds and waste time understanding their mistakes....

Comment: I copied this and it almost works, I however do now get the following error: main.cpp|31|error: variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but incomplete type|. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Aesir [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=variable+istringstream+has+initializer+but+incomplete+type) -> [`#include <sstream>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091976/using-istringstream-gives-error-why).

Comment: @Aesir You are missing one include, most likely <sstream>

Comment: Ah I did include Istream, tnx.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::istringstream s( theString );
s >> theDouble;
```

`s` now contains the rest of the string, which can easily be extracted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed format for your input. You can, first split it with space. Then you have following:

```
DOUBLE
REST OF STRING THAT I ALSO NEED TO SAVE.
```

Split:

```
std::string str = "3.66 somestring";
std::stringstream ss(str);
std::string buffer;
while(std::getline(ss, buffer, ' ')) {
  // add necessary data to containers...
}
```

Now you can use `std::atof` to parse your double.

edit: Added split code:

Comment: @Dukeling: I meant, one double, one space and rest is string. In that case, splitting from space should work.